# How can I reset a Hotmail password if I don't know the security question?

Tags: outlook.com, password-recovery

My sister recently changed her Hotmail password and she can't reset it, because the security question looks like this:

[image: reset password screenshot]

The question was written long time ago in Greek and apparently Microsoft doesn't display it right. Is there another way of reseting it besides these two options?

She is using a Password Safe for her passwords, but probably she didn't save this one and then totally forgot it.

Comment: I'm Greek and I know a lil bit of web encoding so... Your sister's secret question is "Αγαπημένη ταινία" which stands for "Favorite movie" in English. Hope this tip helps... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are instructions for various ways of getting your account back in this scenario up on the Windows Live help forums:

http://windowslivehelp.com/solution.aspx?solutionid=bf5d34bf-db28-44ca-ac9a-93838d81b2d6

Comment: That looks promising..! Especially this link :) http://windowslivehelp.com/passwordreset.aspx let's see if she'll manage to get it reseted..

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that this could just be the Hotmail servers detecting that you're using English Windows and English web browser. I don't know what you've got available but it might be worth visiting the page on a PC that's set up all in Greek, and see if it sends you a readable version.

Comment: It's probably encoded wrongly on their side.. and I'm pretty sure that the answer is corrupted as well, so it won't work. I'll give it a shot anyway..

Comment: Also just noticed the screenshot looks distinctly Mac-ish, subsititute "Windows" for "Mac" where appropriate!